# Convert the string "%Y-%M-%D" to "YYYY-MM-DD" for use in openpyxl NamedStyle number_format

Tags: python, datetime, openpyxl

TLDR: This is *not* a question about how to change the way a date is converted to a string, but how to convert between the two *format* types - This being "%Y" and "YYYY", the first having a `%` and the second having 4 x `Y`.

I have the following date format "`%Y-%M-%D`" that is used throughout an app. I now need to use this within a openpyxl NamedStyle as the number_format option. I cant use it directly as it doesn't like the format, it needs to be in "`YYYY-MM-DD`" (Excel) format.

1. Do these two formats have names? (so I can Google a little more)
2. Short of creating a lookup table for each combination of `%Y` or `%M` to `Y` and `M` is there a conversion method? Maybe in `openpyxl`? I'd prefer not to use an additional library just for this!

TIA!

Comment: `%Y-%m-%d` is the format you are looking for. You can see all the codes here - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Comment: Thanks, but it's not - openpyxl format only takes non % based formats as far as I have tested

Comment: The format you specify is the *Excel* format that's used to display dates. There's no single Excel format and dates aren't even stored as strings. They are stored as OADate doubles, with a date style. Python format strings don't apply here.

Comment: You can find the format string you want by opening the file in Excel and modifying its style. If you can set `YY-M-D` in Excel, you can do the same with `openpyxl` and a custom style

Comment: Please see the TLDR in the question - I want to convert between the string "YYYY" and "%Y" - this is evidently nothing to do with dates, datetime or openpyxl.

Comment: Additionally, I already use the python format "%Y" in other parts of my app to display the date (so I cannot change it, and I dont want to have two different date format options). I want to use this same "string" in an `openpyxl` style, but I cant because it requires "YYYY" (Without the %, and 4x "Y")

Comment: Your question is confusing (evidently from all the comments as well). In Python dates should always be dealt with as objects (either `date` or `datetime` objects). Only while outputting those as strings you add the `format` to them. As such, elsewhere you will use the `datetime` format scheme (i.e - `%Y-%m-%d`) while with `openpyxl` you will just put the `datetime` object as the value of the cell (`cell.value = some_datetime`) and adjust its `number_format` to your liking, in this case `YYYY-MM-DD` which is the Excel schema for date formatting.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I know what you are saying. I have a format such as '%Y' (which was given by the user to format something else in my app), but `openpyxl` _does not accept this format_ *and I dont want to have to ask the user for a new format (i.e. "`YYYY`")*. Again, this is not a question about data-structures, it boils down to `openpyxl` not accepting `%Y`

Comment: I came up with the following crude conversion that worked: ```fmt_replacers = [
        ('%a', 'ddd'),
        ('%A', 'dddd'),
        ('%w', 'd'),
        ('%d', 'dd'),
        ('%b', 'mmm'),
        ('%B', 'mmmm'),
        ('%m', 'mm'),
        ('%y', 'yy'),
        ('%Y', 'yyyy'),
        ('%H', 'hh'),
        ('%I', 'hh'),
        ('%p', 'AM/PM'),
        ('%M', 'mm'),
        ('%S', 'ss'),
        ('%f', 'ss.00'),
        ('%c', 'ddd mmm dd hh:mm:ss yyyy'),
        ('%x', 'mm/dd/yyyy'),
        ('%X', 'hh:mm:ss'),
        ('%%', '%')
    ]```

Comment: he wants to convert from 1989 C format to ISO 8601 format, how hard is that to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a mapping between printf-style and Excel formatting. Individual date formats don't have names. And, due to the way Excel implements number formats I can't think of an easy way of covering all the possibilities. NamedStyles generally refer to a collection of formatting options such as font, border and not just number format.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I thought, I went with a mapping but they dont exactly fit together exactly which is even more of a pain... And position of `M` matters in Excel formats which while isn't a deal breaker, it could lead to some unseen issues... E.g. I want `%D %M`, `day minute`, but if I map this directly to `D M` for excel it'll give me 'day month' :( there is no explicit `minute` in Excel and it depends on the order... Well done M$!

Comment: Yeah, loads of gotchas in there! For "fun", you can read the EBNF specification and try and write an implementation…

Comment: No thanks  it did look interesting though, learn something new every day etc.! Thanks